# Can my TControl be notified when its parent form is shown (DoShow)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

How can my `TControl` descendant  get notified when its Parent Form in Showing i.e. the Parent Form `DoShow` method is called?

Is there a message being broadcast to the children (and children or children) when that occurs?

In my specific case, it is a `TCustomControl` (not `TGraphicsControl`). so maybe it will be easier?

Thanks.

Comment: There's `CM_SHOWINGCHANGED` but it will be sent only when `Showing` is changed. Practically only the first time the control is shown (i.e. not when the form is hidden and shown again). Would you like to tell about the 'X' issue?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, `CM_SHOWINGCHANGED` will be sent by the form to my control? and BTW, why the downvote?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, the "X" issue is this: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22450671/Automatically-center-components-on-my-form-upon-maximizing.html#a18748856

Comment: I want to do a similar control but to call `RegisterPositions` from within my `TAlignPanel`. note the comment: `You have to call the AlignPanel.Registerpositions in your formshow event`

Comment: A wincontrol, in its `UpdateShowing`, calls its children to `UpdateShowing`. If `Showing` is changed, then the message is performed.

Comment: Difficult to see the connection between showing a form and sizing it.

Comment: Yep, rather looks like an alignment problem.

Comment: @David, When the form is first shown, the panel stores ** initial** position of the panel child controls. then when it is resized the controls are scaled.

Comment: Sounds to me like the work is best done by the form